# Add a command in google assistant to trigger a function in your android app

Tags: android, voice, google-assistant-sdk

I can use the google assistant to open an application, but can I also add a phrase to the google assistant which triggers a particular function in my application?

Eg.

```
saying "Ok google. resume stopwatch in blahblahApp"
```

should trigger a function (say `ResumeStopwatch()`)  in my app `blahblahApp`.

A way to either customize my device for this capability or integrating some package in my app to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) which gives a way for a user to give commands which can trigger some execution [in your app](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/action-schema).